# What are some examples of LaTeX commands which accept three or more arguments?

Tags: macros, arguments

The `\binom` command is an example of a LaTeX command which accepts two inputs.

We have the following example:

```
\binom{n+1}{2k}
```

What is an example of a LaTeX command with three or more parameters?

Comment: Do you mean commands in the LaTeX kernel or do you want to include commands from any of the hundreds of packages?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL presumably any package as the `\binom ` example in the question is not defined by the latex format

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of version 2022-11-01, patch level 1, the LaTeX "kernel" contains

- 10 instances of `#9`
- 30 instances of `#8`
- 40 instances of `#7`
- 86 instances of `#6`
- 172 instances of `#5`
- 407 instances of `#4`
- 892 instances of `#3`

This translates into (very!) roughly 5, 10, 5, 23, 43, 117, and 242 kernel commands taking *exactly* 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, and 3 arguments, respectively. Of course, many (most?) kernel commands that take 5 or more inputs are not user-level commands. Instead, they are part of an erector set of tools meant to create further tools, including user-level commands.

To give an example of a *user-level* command provided by one of the myriad of available LaTeX packages, consider `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, which is provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package. E.g.,

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

And an example from the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package:

```
\crefname{prop}{proposition}{propositions}
```

Of course, I make no claim whatsoever that these two commands are somehow representative of the vast number of LaTeX commands out there that take exactly three arguments.

Comment: It is nice to see someone use the word "Kernel" outside of the context of documentation for the Linux operating system. In general, it is useful to the word "***Kernel***" within the context of any kind of computer programming to mean, "the core functionality of a system without any additional add-ons or seldom used libraries, features, packages, etc..." or maybe "The main thing without any extra bells, whistles, or buttons."

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon looking in ltnews I see "LaTeX Kernel" being used a far back as the June 1995 issue, so almost as long ago as "Linux Kernel" (1991, I think)

Answer (score 9):

The question is rather under specified, but for example

`\newenvironment` has 0 parameters considered as a tex macro (the same is true of `\binom`)

`\show\newenvironment`  shows

```
> \newenvironment=macro:
->\@star@or@long \new@environment .
l.4 \show\newenvironment
```

But considered as a latex command it has 3 or 5 depending if you count optional parameters, or 4 or 6 if you count `*`

```
\newenvironment{foo1}{start}{end}

\newenvironment{foo2}[2][default]{start}{end}

\newenvironment*{foo3}[2][default]{start}{end}
```

Comment: Is the following what you meant by the phrase "*under-specified question*". Would you consider a question **q** to be under-specified if and only if for any **a** if **a** is an answer to question **q**, then there exists **α** such that **α** is a correct answer to question **q** and **a ≠α**. For example, if I asked, "What is the title of the last book I read" the answer might be [*Dance Me Outside*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_Me_Outside_(short_story_collection)). The problem with that answer is that a copy of the book with GPS coords in Canada on May 25th 2023 is not the same book.

Comment: In my earlier very long comment, my point was to prove that there does not exist a unique correct answer to most questions. It almost makes no sense to say, "this is a bad question, because the correct answer is not unique."

Comment: @Carlisle If you think that an answer **a** is unique, I can usually cook up an answer **α** which is derived from answer **a** and answer **α** has the same semantic meaning, but is slightly different. Because they are different in some way, it cannot be the same answer.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon the problem is not that there is more than one answer, it's that there isn't really any answer as the terms in the question are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Think at the package `tcolorbox` that ha a lot ov parameter in his implementation. You ca specify in Your program a few of this in extenso like in this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    %\flushbottom
    \lipsum[6]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\huge Prova di titolo},% <-- commenta se npn vuoi il titolo
        colbacktitle=cyan,
        boxsep=5pt, 
        left=35pt, 
        right=35pt, 
        top=15pt, 
        bottom=15pt,
        before upper={\parindent 0pt},
        breakable=true,
        colback=cyan!20,
        %empty % <-- decommenta se non vuoi fondo e cornice
        ]
    \lipsum[1][1-4]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \par
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\huge Prova di titolo},% <-- commenta se npn vuoi il titolo
        colbacktitle=gray,
        boxsep=2pt, 
        left=5pt, 
        right=5pt, 
        top=5pt, 
        bottom=5pt,
        before upper={\parindent 0pt},
        breakable=true,
        colback=gray!10,
        %empty % <-- decommenta se non vuoi fondo e cornice
        ]
        \lipsum[2][3-7]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \par
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\huge Prova di titolo},% <-- commenta se npn vuoi il titolo
        colbacktitle=blue,
        left skip=30pt,
        right skip=30pt,
        coltitle=yellow,
        boxsep=2pt, 
        left=0pt, 
        right=0pt, 
        top=5pt, 
        bottom=5pt,
        before upper={\parindent 0pt},
        breakable=true,
        colback=cyan!10,
        %empty % <-- decommenta se non vuoi fondo e cornice
        ]
        \lipsum[2][1-4]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \par
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%title={\huge Prova di titolo},% <-- commenta se npn vuoi il titolo
        colbacktitle=blue,
        left skip=30pt,
        right skip=30pt,
        coltitle=yellow,
        boxsep=2pt, 
        left=0pt, 
        right=0pt, 
        top=5pt, 
        bottom=5pt,
        before upper={\parindent 0pt},
        breakable=true,
        colback=cyan!10,
        %empty % <-- decommenta se non vuoi fondo e cornice
        ]
        \lipsum[2][1-4]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[9]\par
    %\pagebreak
    \lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

or define in the preamble a new command with 5 or 6 paramenters and then You call in the body of the program the box You need with the appropriates parameters. The result is the same but I think the first method is better and more easy.
Other thing if You want to draw a regular poligon with his circle around: three parameters, radius, n of vertex, starting angle. If You want add a forth parameter: edges color.

Comment: This does not really count as multiple _arguments_ though. Things like `colbacktitle=gray` or `boxsep=2pt` are called _options_ in tcolorbox and the full list of options is a single argument for the `\begin` command.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily, `newcommand` itself takes 4 arguments:

```tex
\newcommand{name}[num][default]{definition}
```

If you consider the `*` in `\newcommand*` an argument, it's 5.